# While com operador lógico "ou" - C++

Tags: c++

Estou com problemas para terminar um algoritmo.

Quando insere um *loop* `while` para não permitir que seja digitado uma forma inválida, o código apresenta erro na execução. Caso alguém me ajude dando alguma dica ou solução, fico grato.

Segue trecho do código:

```
printf("\n     DESEJA CONTINUAR O PROGRAMA?(YES ou NOT)== : ");                   
fflush(stdin);
gets(continuar);
strupr(continuar);
while((strcmp(continuar, "YES"!=0)) || (strcmp(continuar, "NOT"!=0))){
    printf("     \nDIGITE UMA FORMA VALIDA! (YES ou NOT)");                       
}
```

Comment: `"YES"!=0`, esse `!=0` não deveria estar fora da função `strcmp`?

Comment: Isso mesmo Anderson, erro infantil meu. Muito Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Erro de parentização:

```
while((strcmp(continuar, "YES")!=0) || (strcmp(continuar, "NOT")!=0)){
```

e creio que o OU neste caso não atenderá ao que você espera já que se for ou "YES" ou "NOT" continuará executando o loop o que não me parece ser o que deseja.

Já que você diz que está utilizando C++ por que não utiliza o compare da classe `<string>`?

```
while ((continuar.compare("YES") != 0) && (continuar.compare("NOT") != 0)) {
```

Comment: Sim, você está certo. Cometi um erro bobo inserindo o operador lógico junto com a função strcmp, como testei outras formas antes de ver o erro, postei utilizando o operador errado, mas já corrigo o código. Muito Obrigado.